# Using a variable as a default value in vars_prompt in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I was trying to use `vars_prompt` in Ansible with default values taken from facts (or otherwise a previously defined variable). The playbook is intended be used as an ad-hoc one for initial provisioning.

My playbook:

```
---
- hosts: server01
  gather_facts: True
  vars_prompt:
    - name: new_hostname
      prompt: please enter the name for the target
      default: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
      private: no
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ new_hostname }}"
```

Current result:

```
please enter the name for the target [{{ ansible_hostname }}]:
ERROR! 'ansible_hostname' is undefined
```

Expected results (assuming `ansible_hostname=server01`:

```
please enter the name for the target [server01]:
```

Is it possible to achieve in Ansible?

Comment: I bet you are out of luck here. There are no host variables at this stage – prompts are for whole play and questions you before any task (including setup) is done for any host. May be `{{ new_hostname | default(ansible_hostname) }}` and passing `new_hostname` with `-e` is a solution.

Comment: "*There are no host variables at this stage*" -- the question is: are there any variables interpreted at this stage (it seems any is just treated as a string). Other than that, I started to wonder if I could create a dynamic playbook from j2 template locally and include it..

Comment: Quick look to the code hints that this part of playbook is not templated.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I meant I will try to create a playbook which will locally create another (ephemeral) playbook from j2 template (filling the values) and run this subplaybook from the main playbook.

Comment: Yes even I experienced the same issue. On one error scenario, I wanted to get a user input whether to continue the flow or quit. But the prompting happens before executing any task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be implemented using the [`pause` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/pause_module.html):

```
---
- hosts: server01
  gather_facts: True
  tasks:
    - pause:
        prompt: please enter the name for the target [{{ ansible_hostname }}]
      register: prompt

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ prompt.user_input if prompt.user_input else ansible_hostname }}"
```